# How to trim extra space left and right to special music symbols?

Tags: android, typeface

I would like to draw text with special music symbols. For example, tuning names like EADGBE, E#A#D#G#B#E# (sharps and flats should be Unicode symbols u266F and u266D. The problem is a very big space left and right to special symbol.

I've also found that is problem not only for sharp and flat but also for some another music symbols.

There are the code and result:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFG\n");
    sb.append("\u266F\u266F\u266F\n");
    sb.append("\u266D\u266D\u266D\n");
    for (int j = 10; j < 16; j++) {
        int charIndex = (2 * 16 * 16 * 16) + (6 * 16 * 16) + 6 * 16 + j;
        Character ch = Character.valueOf((char) charIndex);
        sb.append(ch);
    }
```

[image: Symbols]

I've tried to use another fonts (for example, I've downloaded Helvetica and Helvetica Neue fonts, put them in assets and set them on TextView) but nothing change: there is a very big space left and right to symbol.

Is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not white space... i run your code and print each character on  logcat. and i found that: on your image appears only 4 symbols but logcat display 6, maybe the font not support that kind of symbol.

```
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9834 = ♪
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9835 = ♫
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9836 = ♬
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9837 = ♭
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9838 = ♮
09-03 09:14:42.092: D/asd-asdasd(7486): Test character: 9839 = ♯
```

Comment: As you can see, there is a big whitespace around of sharp and flat in 2nd and 3rd lines. That's an issue.